# Rails_admin, how to create forms for custom actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rails-admin

I have generated my custom action [by this link on wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action). I have created class which inherits from `RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base`.

I have created my view for this action in `rails_admin_my_action/app/views/rails_admin/main/my_action.html.erb`

When we create forms for your controllers, we mostly use `form_for` which will go to my controller and do specific action, but I think in `rails_admin` there something else, because rails_admin uses his own controllers which is generated from `RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base`.

How to create forms for my custom rails_admin actions?

I'm asking this because there is no proper documentation about this.

My view for my action is like this:

```
<h3>Manage state of <%= @object.name %></h3>
```

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

  <% @object.state_events.each do |event| %>
      <label class="btn bnt-lg btn-default">
        <%= form.radio_button :state, event, autocomplete: 'off' %> <%= event %>
      </label>

<% end %>


</div>

<br/>

<hr/>

<%= form.submit 'Change', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary'  %>
```

In `lib/my_action.rb` I just copied `register_instance_option :controller` of `edit` action.

When I submit my form. I get `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your action, so [take a look](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/tree/master/app/views/rails_admin/main) how templates are implemented. Basically `form_tag my_action_path` or `form_for @object, url: my_action_path(@abstract_model, @object.id)` should work. FYI you may [define custom action](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions#define-actions) right in rails_admin config:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.actions do
    member :my_action do
      only ['MyModel']
      http_methods { [:post, :get] }

      controller do
        proc do
          if request.get?
          elsif request.post?
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have created as you said. However, I get no routes matches error, when I submit my form to my controller.

Comment: execute `rake routes`, find your action for `RailsAdmin::Engine` and use `"#{your_action_name}_path"` helper

Comment: you need to define `http_methods` option. by default it is `:get` only. see possible options: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/base.rb

Comment: That worked well. Now when I submit my form I get `Forbidden attributes error`. Where to allow my attributes?

Comment: post how and where did you define custom action and also the content of `my_action.html.erb`

Comment: hm, what's the point of custom action if you copied edit action from source? you could just use it. i don't know what you want to achieve, but write anything you want like in normal controller with access to `@object` instance. `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` is related to http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html if you use rails 4.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize Rails Admin's controller instead of implementing your own, e.g. if you simply need to customize the form for your custom action and no other logic involved.

To do so, after adding the actual *Action* you also need to add a *Section*, same way but inherit from `RailsAdmin::Config::Sections::Base`.

So if your custom action is called "Cancel" in the lib directory you may have something like this:

```
rails_admin/
└── config/
    └── actions/
    │   └── cancel.rb
    └── sections/
        └── cancel.rb
```

Your action could be as follows:

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/edit'

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Cancel < Edit
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'fa fa-ban'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see you don't have to implement the controller Proc, it will be inherited from the default "Edit" action.

The section code could look pretty simple, here's mine:

```
require 'rails_admin/config/sections'
require 'rails_admin/config/sections/edit'

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Sections
      class Cancel < Edit
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in the `rails_admin.rb`:

```
require "rails_admin/config/actions/cancel"
require "rails_admin/config/sections/cancel"
```

Now let's take a look at `RailsAdmin::Config::Sections`, it implements the `.included` method, which is the cause why nothing will work at this moment ;)

This module is included into `RailsAdmin::Config::Model` and defines these configuration methods you use to define sections in the config: `list`, `edit`, `update`, etc. And your custom section doesn't work because `.included` executes before your new section is loaded.

To fix this I added a patch for `RailsAdmin::Config::Model` which re-executes the method once more, after all my custom sections were loaded. Here's the code (not the best way, but I am too lazy):

```
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    class Model
      # Re-execute included(self) to register custom sections
      RailsAdmin::Config::Sections.included(self)
    end
  end
end
```

A better option would be to implement the `.register` method, like `RailsAdmin::Config::Actions` does and not re-define already existing methods.

Then your `rails_admin.rb` will look like this:

```
require "rails_admin/config/actions/cancel"
require "rails_admin/config/sections/cancel"
require "monkey/rails_admin/config/model"

RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.actions do
    # ...
    cancel
  end

  config.model "ModelName" do
    cancel do
      field :name
    end
  end
end
```

That's it, now in your `cancel.haml` you can add (copied from default edit template):

```
= rails_admin_form_for @object, url: edit_path(@abstract_model, @object.id), as: @abstract_model.param_key, html: { method: "put", multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal denser", data: { title: @page_name } } do |form|
  = form.generate action: :cancel
```

The only difference here is the action name, passed to `#generate`. Rails Admin will generate the form for you and submit it to its own "Main" controller. If you need to add some custom logic to the action then you can implement the controller proc in your action and it will be called instead.

Have fun!

Comment: > A better option would be to implement the `.register`
Could you show example of how to do that, and how we will be using this new method?